# Upgrading slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar file in Grails (1.3.x) to a newer one, what to consider?

Tags: grails, slf4j, logback

I'm planning to replace log4j with logback. In order to get Groovy configuration (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) to function, I need at least logback-0.9.22.

The problem is that Grails 1.3.x ships with slf4j-api-1.5.8 which is only enough to use logback-0.9.17 which, in turn, does not support Groovy configuration.

What does actually happen (does something break / causes unexpected situations) if I upgrade slf4j-api in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See slf4j release history at http://slf4j.org/news.html.

The 1.6.0 version lists only one incompatibility:

> The log method in LocationAwareLogger interface now admits an
>   additional parameter of type Object[] representing additional
>   arguments of the log request. Due to this modification, slf4j-api
>   version 1.6.x will not work with bindings shipping with SLF4J 1.5.x --
>   bindings shipping with 1.6.x must be used.

I guess this is the exact single reason that slf4j-api-1.5.8 and logback-0.9.22 don't match.

So after upgrading both slf4j-api and logback everything should just work.

Comment: This was fairly easily done by modifying the BuildConfig.groovy by excluding older versions of slf4j and defining newer versions for runtime, build & compile.